# Strapi V4 Next js [slug].js is not working getStaticPaths() getStaticProps()

Tags: next.js, strapi

I develop with Strapi V4 and Next

migrating V3 to V4

[slug].js this file was happened error

I don't know the reasons

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJbvZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKAdh.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code, anything text-based should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try adding the .attributes on line 62 and .data on line 78, check what you get from the fetch call

```
62 - evt.attributes.slug

78 - events.data[0]
```